# Can't play this Video - Android Studio

Tags: php, android, video

I hope you are having a great day. I am trying to display a video within my app. Most videos that are originated from an online source (created from sources other than being captured by my samsung phone) work if not all. Whenever I use a video that I import using php. It works very well on php but not on android. I wonder if you can help me figure out a solution for this problem. The videos that I capture within my phone are mp4 videos which should be supported by android.
Here is my android code:

```
VideoView v = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.100:8080/PhpProject2/download1.php?id=2");
v.setVideoURI(uri);
v.start();
linearLayout.addView(v);
```

You can request my php code if you are interested but it is functional, I tested it. I suspect the problem is within on the android side. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I assume that codec and size are supported within android

Comment: Use this - https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player . It will also provide buffering feature (I haven't used it yet)